# Calling a method with it's previous values on a single line

Tags: java

So I have a quite simple method, which has only one job, it has to give me the min and max values of a chaning variable.

```
    public int[] axisLimits(int axisInfo, int axisMin, int axisMax){

    if(axisInfo >= axisMax){
        axisMax = axisInfo;
    }else if(axisInfo < axisMin){
        axisMin = axisInfo;
    }


    int axisLimits[] = {axisMin, axisMax};
    /*
    axisLimits[0] = axisMin;
    axisLimits[1] = axisMax;
    */
    return axisLimits;
}
```

Previously I had it with int axisLimits[] = new int[2],  that's why I have those two lines commented.

So it's works fine, but I have to predefine 2 variable for every axis, and save the min and max values before the next call:

```
    int limitZ[] = new Limits().axisLimits((int)accelZ, minAccelZ, maxAccelZ);
    minAccelZ = limitZ[0];
    maxAccelZ = limitZ[1];
```

And than I can use the minAccelZ and max AccelZ or the limitZ[0] and the limitZ[1].

Is there any way to go around this and make it a single line call? (So I can work with limitZ[0] and limitZ[1] as needed?

Comment: Not clearly expressed. .

Comment: What about making `axisMin` and `axisMax` class variables?

Comment: Yes pass in an `array` with 2 elements min/max instead of individually passing them in...or create a class with min and max attributes and pass the class in.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public int[] axisLimits(int ...intvalues){

            int axisLimits[] = new int [intvalues.length];
            int arrayofints[] = intvalues;
            arrayofints[2] = (arrayofints[0] >= arrayofints[2]) ? arrayofints[0] : arrayofints[2]; //axismax
            arrayofints[1]  = (arrayofints[0] < arrayofints[1] ) ? arrayofints[0] : arrayofints[1]; //axismin

            //int axisInfo = arrayofints[0]
            //int axisMin =arrayofints[1] 
            //int axisMax = arrayofints[2]

            int index = 0;
            for (int intvalue : arrayofints) {
                axisLimits[index] = intvalue;
                ++index;
            }        


        return axisLimits;
        }
```

maybe this approach can help you i have changed the method to accept any no of int values and you dont have to worry creating an array and adding values 
to array manually this will do the job

Comment: you dont have to create classes to accomplish the task a single conditional operator does the job for you

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class for that like this, it kinda is the Java way:

```
public class AxisLimit {
    private int min, max;

    public AxisLimit(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public int min() {
        return min;
    }

    public int max() {
        return max;
    }
}
```

And change your code to this:

```
public static AxisLimit axisLimit(int axisInfo, AxisLimit axisLimit){
    int max = axisLimit.max();

    if(axisInfo > max) {
        return new AxisLimit(axisLimit.min(), axisInfo);
    } 

    if(axisInfo < min) {
        return new AxisLimit(axisInfo, axisLimit.max());
    }

    return new AxisLimit(axisLimit.min(), axisLimit.max());
}
```

and this:

```
AxisLimit limitZ = Limits.axisLimits((int)accelZ, minAccelZ, maxAccelZ);
minAccelZ = limitZ.min();
maxAccelZ = limitZ.max();
```

Notice you can make Limits.axisLimits(int, int, int) static and that saves you from creating a new instance on every call.

Once you achieve this you can expand even more on your OO skills. Since it is the responsibility of a limit to know how to expand itself to contain a value. You can refactor it like this:

```
public class AxisLimit {
    private int min, max;

    public AxisLimit(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public int max() {
        return max;
    }

    public int min() {
        return min;
    }

    public AxisLimit containing(int axisInfo) {
        if(axisInfo > max) {
            return new AxisLimit(min, axisInfo);
        } 

        if(axisInfo < min) {
            return new AxisLimit(axisInfo, max);
        }

        return new AxisLimit(min, max);
    }
}
```

delete the static method :)

and the caller block becomes:

```
AxisLimit limitZ = new AxisLimit(axisMin, axisMax).containing((int)accelZ);
```

and you can joyfully use `limitZ.min()` and `limitZ.max()` where appropriate or store them in a variable as in the first example.

Notice how the code became more readable? the variable names are simpler, that is usually a sign you are architecting your solution in the right direction.

Comment: I like how fast you have made this and ready to give you the green checkmark. But after correcting the not maching variables in your code (info vs axisInfo) I have got an error on these two lines: 
AxisLimit.max(); and AxisLimit.min(); eclipse is telling me that "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method max() from the type AxisLimit"  + I am not sure what you have meant on currentLimitZ.

Comment: There is no place in the code where I call AxisLimit.min() or AxisLimit.max() only axisLimit.min() and axisLimit.max(). Renamed the method to axisInfo.

Comment: currentLimitZ -> AxisLimit limitZ = currentLimitZ cannot be resolved

Comment: `currentLimitZ` is the limit when you reach this point in the code. In your example it's `axisMin` and `axisMax`, you can create it with `AxisLimit currentLimitZ = new AxisLimit(axisMin, axisMax);`

Comment: Ah, is there any way to skip this part? Like it's automatically done with (-1,1) and I only have to work with one line. AxisLimit limitZ = currentLimitZ.containing((int)accelZ);

Comment: AxisLimit limitZ = new AxisLimit(axisMin, axisMax).containing((int)accelZ);

Comment: It's not working like I would expect it to be. It's not keeping the min and max values.

Answer (score 0):

How about a class like:

```
public class MinMax {

    private int min;
    private int max;

    public MinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public MinMax axisInfo(int axisInfo) {
        if ( axisInfo > max ) max = axisInfo;
        else if ( axisInfo < min ) min = axisInfo;
        return this;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
MinMax m = new MinMax(100,1000)
        .axisInfo(1500)
        .axisInfo(90)
        .axisInfo(70);

int min = m.getMin();
int max = m.getMax();
```